# Is it possible to perfom a fulltext search against a joined column?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, full-text-search

Hello I' trying to select from joined column:

```
SELECT 
   A.idAd,
   A.ads_in_Cat,
   A.title,
   A.currency,
   A.price,
   A.in_dpt,
   A.description,
   D.*, 
   S.* 
FROM ads A
LEFT JOIN dept D ON D.id_dept = A.in_dpt
LEFT JOIN sub_cat_ad AS  ON S.id_sub_cat = A.ads_in_Cat
WHERE MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST(:searchTerm) 
   OR MATCH (S.sub_cat_name) AGAINST(:searchTerm)
```

Could someone please tell me why MySQL returns : 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list in... unless I use IN BOOLEAN MODE?

PS the table S has fulltext defined for each colunm. MySQL ver 5.1.49

Comment: I notice you're missing a comma after `A.title`, though I doubt that that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, that would crash the query in a completely different way. I edited and added the comma.

Comment: For that matter, you have `WHERE MATCH(A.titlee,` instead of `WHERE MATCH(A.title,`. I assume this isn't a direct copy and paste of the query. If you can, perhaps you should replace this example with a copy and paste of the real one?

Comment: Thanks, yes u right @Dan Breslau, it's not a direct copy.

Comment: @Dan Breslau, i don't get the error when I use IN BOOLEAN MODE

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza, yes u got it, this would crash the query with a unknown Colunm error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get the error when you use:

```
   SELECT A.idAd,
          A.ads_in_Cat,
          A.title,
          A.currency,
          A.price,
          A.in_dpt,
          A.description,
          D.*, 
          s.* 
     FROM ads A
LEFT JOIN dept D ON D.id_dept = A.in_dpt
LEFT JOIN sub_cat_ad s ON s.id_sub_cat = A.ads_in_Cat
                      AND MATCH (s.sub_cat_name) AGAINST(:searchTerm) 
    WHERE MATCH(A.title, A.description) AGAINST(:searchTerm)
```

Comment: @jartaud: What if you don't include the FTS on `sub_cat_ad` at all?  It's help to know the search term you're testing with, too.

Comment: POnies Yes, cause the user can search by title, description or just entering the category name

Comment: @jartaud: I understand what you want; I'm trying to diagnose if it's a specific field that is triggering the error & requirement to use `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

Comment: yes everythnig works great if I dont include the FTS on sub_cat_ad. Donno, but it seems MySQL 5.1.49 ignores the defined fulltext indices.